# How draw a circular progress bar with CAShapLayer and auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I'm drawing a circular progress bar using `CAShapeLayer`, I can produce it only if I center it on my view. Now I want to constraint it to the trailing edge of my card view. Below is my code:

```
let center = cardView.center
//track layer
let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1
trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
trackLayer.lineWidth = 5
cardView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

//progress Layer
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
//NumberFormatter().number(from: percentageUsed) as! CGFloat
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.6
shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
cardView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Now I wish i could do something like

```
shapeLayer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardVeiw.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Comment: i dont think its a right way for constraint

Comment: @AnkitKushwah So the best way is to just use UIView to draw the shape? If so it will be difficult for me to draw the progress shape strokeEnd

Comment: yes you have to draw the shape from Draw method  and use bezire path for creating shapes

Comment: @AnkitKushwah not quite clear can you please explain further and probably a code will do. Thanks